# Where to add my ojdbc jar in glassfish?

Tags: oracle, glassfish

I need to connect my glassfish to my oracle database and I use **OracleXADataSource** but i have a problem locating the right path in my glassfish as to where i need to place it.
I first placed it in this location  C:\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext is it the right path?

Comment: If you create a connection pool, you need an appropriate database driver JAR in the location you mentioned. You can otherwise also add that JAR as a separate library to your application's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: Could your comment mean my location is right? Because if it is so, why I'm getting runtime errors every after restart. I think it have to do with my location or my mismatch of jar to glassfish, could it be?

Comment: im using glassfish 4.1 and ojdbc7-12.0.1 are they match?

Comment: Yes that location is correct. I used `ojdbc6.jar` (11.2.0.3.0) in GlassFish 3.x in the past. I am currently using GlassFish 4.1 but with MySQL (where the driver JAR file (MySQL JDBC Driver) is located/placed in the same location as you mentioned). Therefore, I cannot say for sure, if that driver JAR `ojdbc7-12.0.1` is actually giving you a trouble.